# Can I use jquery-ui autocomplete with Polymer 1.0 paper-input?

Tags: polymer

When I bind the jquery-ui autocomplete to the Polymer 1.0 paper-input, I find that I don't get back the entered text. In the code snippet below, the "req" parameter has a "term" field which should contain any entered text. Instead, it contains gibberish.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function start() {
  $("#searchBox").autocomplete({
    source: function(req, responseFn) {
      console.log(req);
    }
  });
});
</script>
<paper-input id="searchBox"/></paper-input>
```

Is Polymer 1.0 paper-input compatible with jquery-ui autocomplete?